# prisma2 how to relate one-to-many and many-to-one?

Tags: prisma, prisma2

I need some help to understqnd how to set my data modelisation.

What i'm trying to do is :

- Reference a group ID in User model. A user can only be in one group, this is what i've done below.
- Reference in Group Model all users that are inside a group. This is what I need help with.

```
model User {
  id         String   @id @default(uuid())
  email      String   @unique
  role       Role     @default(USER)
  group      Group?   @relation(fields: [group_id], references: [id], onDelete: SetNull) 
  group_id   String   
  created_at DateTime @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime @updatedAt

  @@map("user")
}

model Group {
  id         String   @id @default(uuid())
  name       String
  users      User[]
  created_at DateTime @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime @updatedAt
  deleted    Boolean  @default(false)

  @@map("group")
}
```

How can I make this list of User when I already have  users    User[] for the relation in User model ?

(BTW i've read the doc but i'm totally lost...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is correct, you can use prisma-client to test

This is an example of this relation

```
model Agents {
  id             Int       @id @default(autoincrement()) @db.UnsignedInt
  name           String?   @db.VarChar(255)
  owner          String?   @db.VarChar(255)
  address        String?   @db.Text
  lat            String?   @db.VarChar(10)
  lng            String?   @db.VarChar(10)
  tel            String?   @db.VarChar(13)
  mobile         String?   @db.VarChar(11)
  workTime       String?   @db.VarChar(255)
  province       Provinces @relation(fields: [provinceId], references: [id])
  provinceId     Int       @db.UnsignedInt
  createDateTime DateTime  @default(now()) @db.Timestamp(0)
  updateDateTime DateTime? @db.Timestamp(0)
  @@index([provinceId], name: "provinceId")
  @@map(name: "agents")
}


model Provinces {
  id             Int       @id @default(autoincrement()) @db.UnsignedInt
  name           String?   @db.VarChar(255)
  coords         String?   @db.Text
  createDateTime DateTime  @default(now()) @db.Timestamp(0)
  updateDateTime DateTime? @db.Timestamp(0)
  agents Agents[]
  @@map(name: "provinces")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but In my example I don't understand how I tell the group model, in that I want a list of string inside    users      User[].
It seems that is line here to help referencing a group in my users but it's not made to reference users list in my group.

Comment: Ok i think i start to understand, prisma make this automatic relation so I actually had nothing to do... I thought this thing was a kind of helper to create my first relation.
Prisma is so clever !

Comment: Yes, prisma is very clever and clear to understand, but it 's very new and have very work to do to be better